# Could not find the correct ScopedModel

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am using `ScopedModel` and `ScopedModelDescendent` in my flutter app. The MaterialApp is wrapper within a ScopedModelDescendent widget as shown in the code below.

```
void main() => runApp(new ScopeModelWrapper());

class ScopeModelWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModel<AppModel>(model: AppModel(), child: MyApp());
  }
}

class AppModel extends Model {
  // Some code specific to model, actually a lot of code.
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModelDescendant<AppModel>(builder: (context, child, model) {
      return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Firebase',
        localizationsDelegates: [
          AppLocalizationsDelegate(),
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
        supportedLocales: [
          Locale("nb", ""),
          Locale("en", ""),
        ],
        locale: model.appLocal,
        navigatorObservers: <NavigatorObserver>[routeObserver],
        theme: new ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          primaryColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        ),
        home: SelectDenominationPage(),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

The issue occurs when I navigate to `HomePage`->`Settings` (from the `SelectDenominationPage`). The `Settings` page (or widget) contains some widgets wrapped inside `ScopedModelDescendent` widget and that is what causes the error.

I do not understand why it cannot find a ScopedModel because it is right there at the root of the tree.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Update: I moved the `AppModel` class to its own file and then I changed all my imports from `'appmodel.dart'` to `'package:<projectname>/appmodel.dart'` and it started working. I still do not understand this completely. If we are referencing to the same file, why is it being treated at a different model then?

Comment: Could you post a minimal snippet for the `SelectDenominationPage()` that produces de error?

Comment: I get the error when I navigate to the Settings page via the `Homepage` via the `SelectDenominationPage`. The `Settings` page contains a `ScopedModelDescendent`.

Comment: Is your `AppModel` class declared in your `main.dart`? If so, move it to a different file.

Comment: I did that and modified the imports to use the `package:` notation and it worked.