# ScopedModel in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to create a scoped model in my project , but something is going wrong ..

Model class :

```
 class CartonModel extends Model{
  bool playerState = false;
  bool get getPlayerState => playerState ;
  void stateOff(){
  playerState = false ;
  notifyListeners();
  }
  void stateOn(){
    playerState = true ;
     notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Material App wrapped with Scoped Model :

```
ScopedModel<CartonModel>(
  model: new CartonModel(),
  child: new MaterialApp( // some code )
```

i am using ScopedModelDescendant on an Icon Button :

```
ScopedModelDescendant<CartonModel>(
      builder: (context, child, CartonModel model) =>
          new IconButton(
            icon: new Image.asset(imageUrl),
            iconSize: dimenRatio * 0.25,
            onPressed: () {
              Future<void> bottomSheetAwaitClose =
                  showModalBottomSheet<void>(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return MusicR();
                },
              );

              bottomSheetAwaitClose.then((void value) {
                model.stateOff();
              });
            },
          ),
    ),
```

I have imported all required packages and provided types to ScopedModel<> and ScopedModelDescendant<> , but still getting this runtime error :
Could not find the correct ScopedModel.

is there any thing wrong in this code ? please help

Comment: Code above looks alright. We need more code (a complete runnable example) to say what the issue is.

Comment: thanks for your reply @boformer , it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `CartonModel` class is declared in your main.dart, move it to a different file.

And make sure you declare your imports in the form `'package:<projectname>/cartonmodel.dart'`

Comment: it's in an independent file , and i have imported all required packages

Comment: Well, the answer tries to give you some clues based on this problem that we have already seen several times.In those cases, the above recommendations helped solve the issue. The import format could be a problem even if the analyzer does not complain. Give a look to the solution in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52635852/could-not-find-the-correct-scopedmodel

Comment: it works when i changed all import statements to 'package:<projectname>/filename.dart' , thanks a lot for your help .